# i386 is apparentely the "wrong architecture" for my 32 bit Chromebook running ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, chromebook, crouton

I'm trying to get the latest version of OpenTTD but i386 is the "wrong architecture". amd64 doesn't work either. amd64 and i386 are the only ones available. What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

If your chromebook is ARM based then neither will work and you can't install OpenTTD.

OpenTTD has no port to armhf.